# How to extract time from a date column in the where clause in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I want to select rows with a specific time interval but the date doesn't matter. So I need a function to return just the time part. I tried using:

```
to_char(mydate, 'HH12:MI:SS') between '00:00:00' and '08:00:00'
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why did you use HH12 - that should be OK with HH24? It would be helpful to include *why* it didn't work in your question though; any errors you got, or if you got the wrong results then sample data and what you got, and expected to see. There are other ways though, depending on the range(s) you want. Also be aware that `between` is inclusive, so you might actually want your range to be up to, but not including, 08:00:00.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got the wrong results. It basically acts like there is no time filter and brings all the rows. I'm confused with HH12 and HH24 because my data include AM/PM. So I figured I must use HH12. I need different shifts rows counted. I arranged the date portion with to_char and it works But I can't figure out how to filter time.

Comment: Your data doesn't include AM/PM. Oracle uses an internal representation you don't really need to worry about. Your client is formatting the dates, probably using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session setting, as something like `'DD-Mon-RR HH12:MI:SS AM'`. So it shows you both the 12-hour time and an AM/PM indicator, so it isn't ambiguous. If you only get the time part, without that indicator, then you need HH24 so it is still unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some sample data you can see that using `HH12` doens't necessarly produce the strings you are expecting:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

-- CTE just for dummy data
with mytable (mydate) as (
            select cast(timestamp '2018-08-01 00:00:00' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-02 07:59:59' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-03 08:00:00' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-04 08:00:01' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-05 19:59:59' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-06 20:00:00' as date) from dual
  union all select cast(timestamp '2018-08-07 20:00:01' as date) from dual
)
-- actual query
select mydate,
  to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time_24,
  to_char(mydate, 'HH12:MI:SS') as time_12
from mytable;

MYDATE              TIME_24  TIME_12 
------------------- -------- --------
2018-08-01 00:00:00 00:00:00 12:00:00
2018-08-02 07:59:59 07:59:59 07:59:59
2018-08-03 08:00:00 08:00:00 08:00:00
2018-08-04 08:00:01 08:00:01 08:00:01
2018-08-05 19:59:59 19:59:59 07:59:59
2018-08-06 20:00:00 20:00:00 08:00:00
2018-08-07 20:00:01 20:00:01 08:00:01
```

So when you try to filter using that HH12-based string it includes records you don't expect to see, between 8am and 8pm; and also excludes midnight (as that is '12:00:00' not '00:00:00'):

```
select mydate
from mytable
where to_char(mydate, 'HH12:MI:SS') between '00:00:00' and '08:00:00';

MYDATE             
-------------------
2018-08-02 07:59:59
2018-08-03 08:00:00
2018-08-05 19:59:59
2018-08-06 20:00:00
```

If you use `HH24` instead then you get

```
select mydate
from mytable
where to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') between '00:00:00' and '08:00:00';

MYDATE             
-------------------
2018-08-01 00:00:00
2018-08-02 07:59:59
2018-08-03 08:00:00
```

Also, notice that `between` is inclusive, so it picks up records at exactly 08:00:00. That may not be what you want - if you're splitting the day into three 8-hour periods, you don't data for that second to be included multiple times; so you can use a more explicit range instead:

```
select mydate
from mytable
where to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '00:00:00'
and to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '08:00:00';

MYDATE             
-------------------
2018-08-01 00:00:00
2018-08-02 07:59:59
```

then your second shift is:

```
where to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '08:00:00'
and to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '16:00:00';
```

and your third shift is:

```
where to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '16:00:00';
```

or if you prefer, for consistency:

```
where to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '16:00:00'
and to_char(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS') < '24:00:00';
```

You can't ever get the hour reported as 24 but as it's a string comparison that doesn't matter here, though it is slightly jarring.

Comment: Thanks so much this really helped. It shows the correct results when I use HH24. I am connecting to the database from thingworx platform and my computer doesn't have Oracle so it was really hard for me to try these but this cleared things out for me!

Answer (score -1):

```
TO_CHAR(mydate, 'HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE mydate BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:00:00';
```